# Does Sony Smarteyeglass output video in H.263 or H.264 format?

Tags: sony, sony-smarteyeglass

From SmartEyeglassControlUtils class, it states that the camera output can be 2 modes.
•Picture : Take and store a still image
•JPG Stream : Get JPEG stream data for image recognition

Does it possible to output a real-time video stream in H.263 or H.264 to smartphone? or is it a way to stream the real-time video for broadcasting?

Comment: Can anyone help to answer my question? Can Sony smarteyeglasses stream out the real-time video stream with provided SDK?

Answer (score 1):

JPEG Stream functionality of SmartEyeglass streams images to your application as bitmaps.

You can use this bitmap stream to create a video broadcasting application.

You can consult to this article on details of using SmartEyeglass camera in your application.
https://developer.sony.com/develop/wearables/smarteyeglass-sdk/guides/camera/